# MySQL, create table from TableRow

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I would like to know, if its possible to create a new Table from anothoer existing Tables-Row.
E.G.:

**Table: TablesX**

```
ID  |  user* |  row_1  |  row_2  |  row_3  | etc
----------------------------------------------------
1   |  Carl  | name1   |  name2  |  name3  | etc        -> Create new Table, with refering columns
2   |  Max   | abc1    |  abc2   |  abc3   | etc
```

**Create New table: user***

```
ID  |  user* |  name1  |  name2  |  name3  | etc       <- Insert Row form Table "TablesX"
----------------------------------------------------
1   |  Carl  | info1   |  info2  |  info3  | etc       
2   |  Carl  |     x   |  x      |  x      | etc
```

Isit possible & how can I process?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Yes. It's possible. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically generate the `CREATE TABLE` query by concating the expected query along with the values :

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE TablesX (
  `ID` INTEGER,
  `user*` VARCHAR(4),
  `row_1` VARCHAR(5),
  `row_2` VARCHAR(5),
  `row_3` VARCHAR(5),
  `etc` VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO TablesX
  (`ID`, `user*`, `row_1`, `row_2`, `row_3`, `etc`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'Carl', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'etc'),
  ('2', 'Max', 'abc1', 'abc2', 'abc3', 'etc');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `user*` (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `user*` VARCHAR(255), `', t.row_1, '` VARCHAR(255), `', t.row_2, '` VARCHAR(255), `', t.row_3, '` VARCHAR(255));') "SQL"
FROM TablesX t
ORDER BY t.ID
LIMIT 1;
```

**Output**

```
| SQL                                                                                                                                                        |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| CREATE TABLE `user*` (ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, `user*` VARCHAR(255), `name1` VARCHAR(255), `name2` VARCHAR(255), `name3` VARCHAR(255)); |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wV31BxTnX2TSdiaXFZhYVG/0)

Now, you can [`EXECUTE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execute.html) the query or simply copy/paste and execute it manually